# how to update class library project using a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I m working on a large scale web application using several assemblies (say around 100 assemblies). One of the assemblies is using a web service reference which changed lately. I have updated the web reference URL locally  and build the assembly and its working fine locally. After building the assembly I have moved this dll to the webserver but for some reasons the reference is not updating on the server. Any ideas how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should change web.config on your webserver, because service has changed bindings or url.